# How to install ArUco globally in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, global

I installed the ArUco library by following this tutorial http://miloq.blogspot.com.es/2012/12/install-aruco-ubuntu-linux.html. But I am not managing generate a simple executable. I am trying to change a code line in the aruco_test.cpp (a code one that already comes when you install the library. It's in aruco/utils folder). I want to change the camera used in the code, so that I can use my external web cam rather than using the laptop webcam. Whenever I try to compile the *.cpp file on the linux terminal in order to generate a executable, I receive the following error message:

> g++ aruco_test.cpp -o aruco_test
>
> aruco_test.cpp:31:19: fatal error: aruco.h: No such file or directory
>
> compilation terminated.

A friend of mine said that I didn't install the ArUco library globally, that's why my system can't find the aruco.h. I know where is this header. It's in /usr/local/include/aruco, but I don't know how to say to the system to find this header in that folder.

If the ArUco library had been installed globally, I could compile the *.cpp file by only including "#include aruco.h" in the code.

A aruco_test.cpp code copy is found here: https://github.com/elrond79/aruco/blob/master/utils/aruco_test.cpp

Can somebody, please, help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the makefiles supplied with the package to compile.

In order to figure what commands were originally used to compile perform `make clean` followed by `make -n`.  The latter command would not execute anything but simply emit instructions it would have executed.